# Register dll and ocx file using batch file

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have dll and ocx file on folder on c dirve and want to register just by clicking on batch file

Answer (score 8):

According to [this Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873/en-us):

> #### Regsvr32.exe usage
>
> ```
> RegSvr32.exe has the following command-line options:
> Regsvr32 [/u] [/n] [/i[:cmdline]] dllname
>
> /u - Unregister server
> /i - Call DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline]; when used with /u calls dll uninstall
> /n - do not call DllRegisterServer; this option must be used with /i
> /s – Silent; display no message boxes (added with Windows XP and Windows Vista)
> ```
>
> When you use `Regsvr32.exe`, it attempts to load the component and call its `DLLSelfRegister` function. If this attempt is successful, `Regsvr32.exe` displays a dialog box that indicates success. If the attempt is unsuccessful, `Regsvr32.exe` returns an error message. This may include a Win32 error code.

---

Thus, the resulting batch file will be:

```batch
echo off 
Regsvr32 /s C:\MyDLL.dll
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this batch code:

```
for %%f in (*.ocx *.dll) do regsvr32 %%f
```

Open Notepad and paste in the code, then save the file as `register.bat` and run it as an Administrator.

Comment: You can also add the `/s` flag before the last `%%f` if you don't want a pop-up for each and every one it finds

Answer (score 1):

Just put `regsvr32 pathto.exe` in your batch file, assuming that `regsvr32` is on the path.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run this in silent mode as multiple errors will possibly cause issues with explorer.exe 
for %x in (c:\windows\system32*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %x

Answer (score 0):

Open an Administrative Command Prompt, run the below commands in System32 and SySWoW64 diretories

```
C:\Windows\System32> for %1 in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %1
C:\Windows\SySWow64> for %1 in (*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %1
```